# Error in compiling java servlet program

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have created a java servlet program name **FirstServlet**.

I put it on **Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\FirstServlet.java** and also I set the class path for **servlet-api.jar** but when I compile it

I am finding some error.

Code is :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

   // Runs when the servlet is loaded onto the server.
   public void init() {
      //......
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException {

      // Set the MIME type for the response message
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // Write to network
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      // Your servlet's logic here
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println(" ...... ");
      out.println("</html>");
   }


   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException {
      // do the same thing as HTTP GET request
      doGet(request, response);
   }

   public void destroy() {
    //  ......
   }

}
```

error is :

[image]

Comment: _and also I set the class path for servlet-api.jar_ No, you don't. You ran `javac FirstServlet.java`

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using an IDE? There you might have get the missing library error and organize your libraries as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually providing a classpath entry to the `javac` program. The `servlet-api.jar` is usually included in the `lib` folder of the `Tomcat` installation.

Run it like

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar" FirstServlet.java
```

You would have a much easier (and generally better) time if you used an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ.

Also, don't use the default package.

Comment: now then error is : error while writing FirstServlet:FirstServlet.class(Access is denied)     _public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet{_

Comment: @ManojGupta Do you have write permissions for that folder? I think not.

Comment: @ManojGupta Try running the command line as an administrator or rethink where your Tomcat should be installed. Or change its permissions.

Comment: but it is not running i type in url **http://localhost:8080/classes/FirstServlet**

Comment: @ManojGupta Have you configured the servlet mapping in a `web.xml` descriptor?

Comment: @Manoj That's not an easy question to answer here. [Take a look at this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html). Then search around on google and on this site on how servlet web applications and contexts work.

Comment: What if the servlet depends on others user classes?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802798/compile-servlets-and-others-classes-in-a-java-web-project/42817881

Comment: @Lucas `-cp` expects a `:`  or `;` separated  list of classpath entries. Add the classes you need.

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis I also have tried this command (`javac -cp /opt/tomcat/webapps/compmng/WEB-INF/classes/com/lcdss/compmng/entity:/opt/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar controller/ComputerSV.java`) in many different ways and the same error shows up (Cannot find Symbol Computer).

Comment: Seems the problem was I have not imported the `Computer` class, but now, the new problem is the compiler can't find the package `com.lcdss.compmng.entity` where is the Computer class. I'm not using any IDE, just a text editor, so I may have forgotten something.

Comment: Changing the path to javac -cp `/opt/tomcat/webapps/compmng/WEB-INF/classes`:/opt/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar controller/ComputerSV.java solved the problem.